# A page can have only one server side form tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page `Header.master` which contains a logout button, due to this reason I have to include a form with run at server in my master form.

Again I am using a form in my page because I want to use controls and asp.net compiler says that you cant use controls with form tag with run at server.

**Header.master**

```
<form runat="server"><asp:ImageButton ID="btn_logout" runat="server" OnClick="btn_logout_Click" Height="22px" ImageUrl="~/img/logout.png" Width="43px" /></form>
```

**My Page**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Header.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="student_registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="SCMS.student_registration" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <form id="frm_sr" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: How do you plan to use `frm_sr` form tag?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Form` tag from your page (My Page)

```
<form id="frm_sr" runat="server">
```

`Form` tag in master page is already enclosing all the code written in page itself

`(<asp:Content ID=...>)`